# How to automate/schedule data import to Marketing Cloud from Salesforce Report?

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, import

Good day.
I have a dynamic Salesforce report I want to import to Marketing Cloud (MC) as a data extension (DE).

MC allows you to do this via Email->Interactions->Activities->Import. The challenge is to keep the DE up to date in MC.[image]

Is there a way to schedule import or create an automation that will trigger the update of existing activity?
Is there a better way to SF import report data to MC DE and keep it up to date?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You can do this with Automation Studio. Since your interaction is not triggered by an FTP file drop, you have have to schedule an hourly import job in automation studio. Go to automation studio, drag import to the canvas and select the import activity saved. Then go to schedule and determine how frequently you want this to run. The most regular you can have it is hourly.

Comment: Hey! So on Automation Studio the regular "Import File" activity and then selecting the Import definition should work?

Comment: Bingo! The email studio route was the original way of doing it. Earlier this year SFMC moved some activities to the automation studio tab perhaps because it is more intuitive to set up your activities and automate them in one place

Comment: Since SFMC added guide rails around this it's less of an issue, but make sure your report has "Lead Id" or "Contact Id" as a field label in the report or create a case insensitive 18 character field in CRM to use as our SubsciberKey - https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000005288&language=en_US&type=1. If your report doesn't have "Account Id" or "Lead Id" defined as labels, but calls them ""Customer ID" or "Prospect", you can create a clusterforce.

Comment: The exact steps needs to be taken in current (June 2017) interface:

1) Get to the Automation Studio: Hover the main menu -> Locate Journey Builder Icon (click)
2) Click the button "New Automation" to the right; Select "Schedule" in the pop-up
3) Select (drag and drop to the canvas) "Import File" from the left side menu called "Activities"
4) Choose saved automation
5) Set up schedule and Save the automation

Note: the confusion caused by the name of the "activity": - an automation is recognized as a file in the interface